# Splitting files with redundancy

Tags: algorithm

I need a cmd tool or an algorithm description to do the following:

Given a file of any size (size < 1GB) I need to split the file into n parts (n may be any reasonable number) and 1 file with metadata. 
Metadata is something similar to "parity" byte in RAID systems, that will allow me to restore the whole file if one part of the file is lost. So, the metadata is kind of 'extra' or redundant info that helps to restore original file.
Other n parts should not have any extra information.

For now, I tries to use pacrhive and par2 tools but they don't implement the idea I described above.
Also I tried to get into Forward error corrections (FEC) and Reed-Solomon codes but also didn't succeed there. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a shop, you can't just ask us to get/find/create algorithms/code for you.

Comment: I'm not going to ask for the whole algorithm and source code. Just trying to get the right way for the further investigation, Vallentin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply something almost identical to [RAID 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid_5#RAID_5) (although that's for hard drives, the same logic applies).

So, send the 1st byte to the 1st file, the 2nd to the 2nd, ..., the nth to the nth, the (n+1)th to the 1st, the (n+2)th to the 2nd, etc.

Then just put the parity of each bit across the n files into the last file, i.e.:

```
1st bit of last file = 1st bit of 1st file
                   XOR 1st bit of 2nd file
                   XOR ...
                   XOR 1st bit of nth file

2nd bit of last file = XOR of 2nd bits of all the other files as above
```

This will allow you to restore any file (including the 'metadata' file) by just calculating the parity of the rest of files.

Comment: Thanks, that would be helpful.

Comment: After some attempts I got this approach working with my code, thanks again for the help.